# running Car c=new Driver(); in C#

Tags: c#, class, object

suppose we've two classes Car and Driver,,
and we are able to make object like

```
Car c=new Driver();
```

and able for calling members of Car Class but not of Driver Class Why and When ? ?

Comment: Try posting more of your code -- it's hard to help without more context.

Comment: How would you be able to create an object like that unless `Driver` somehow inherits from `Car` (which doesn't make sense)?

Comment: Mark this as homework, please.

Comment: i know the answer why it is, but i want to know why and when it is possible ?

Answer (score 7):

Even though the reference `c` points to a `Driver` object, the type of the reference (`Car`) determines which methods can be called on it.

As a side note, having `Driver` as a class derived from `Car` does not make much sense. Class inheritance usually can be expressed as a "is-a" relationship, and most drivers are not cars.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `Car` is actually a `Driver`, then you can cast it to a `driver` to access the members of `Driver`. So either

```
((Driver)c).DriverMember();
```

This will throw an exception if `c` is not a `Driver`

Or

```
Driver d = c as Driver;
if( d != null ){
  d.DriverMethod();
}
```

The reason is that since `c` is of type `Car`, then only Car's members are available.

For example, let's say you have `List<Car>` where you add some `Car` objects and some `Driver` objects. Then it gives perfect sense that only `Car`'s members are possible to use.

Also, I assume that `Driver` inherit from `Car` in this case (which is actually a pretty strange inheritance since a driver is **not** a car).

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Car is the base class of driver. This is the point why you can create a new driver object but "put" them into a Car object.

But the reason why only the member of the class "car" are visible is, that your object c is from type Car and not from type Driver and Car has less members than Driver.